# What are the best practices for writing and organizing javascript plugins?

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, organization

So I have a nice chunk of code that is the same across many different javascript files, but I occasionally have to update it due to path changes or other various conditions. Now copy and pasting it all over to the new files works fine but is annoying to execute. Is there a good way to maintain one javascript file with my "plugin" code and have it be accessible by other javascript files that use the plugin?

I am looking for both a good nodejs solution, and vanilla js solution. If they could be mutually shared that'd be ideal, but not required by any means. Ideally, I'd like to host my workspace in `workspace/` and have some folders, `workspace/front-end-js/` and `workspace/back-end-nodejs/`, be able to run code off a plugin in `workspace/plugins/` so that I can execute things like `MyPluginVar.Foo();`

I am aware of some systems, like the node's `var foo = require('bar');` and the frontend browserified version, but really do not know all my options. What's the best way of writing and organizing javascript plugins?

--

*Edit: I'm really trying to avoid npm, but it might be the best option.*

Comment: This is not called "plugin" but "module".

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the clarification +1. I did use the word plugin for a more general sense though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typically add your shared libraries and plugins as dependencies to your project's `package.json` file and install them using npm.

[CommonJS modules](http://www.commonjs.org/specs/modules/1.0/), which use the `module.exports` object and `require` function, are the de facto standard at the moment.

[ES2015 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), which use the `export` and `import` statements, are an emerging formal standard, but support for them is not yet universal. They are a good option if your environment supports them.

To load either type of module on the front end, you will need to use a bundler such as Webpack or Browserify.

Older javascript modules typically publish to the global scope (`window`), and are a simple option for front end code.

You can also support multiple module systems if you like by using a UMD (Universal Module Definition) wrapper. Here's an example from the [UMD Github repo](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) that leverages CommonJS if supported, while falling back to a browser global:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof exports === 'object' && typeof exports.nodeName !== 'string') {
        // CommonJS
        factory(exports, require('b'));
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory((root.commonJsStrictGlobal = {}), root.b);
    }
}(this, function (exports, b) {
    // b represents some dependency

    // attach properties to the exports object to define
    // the exported module properties.
    exports.action = function () {};
}));
```

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to avoid npm as I just want to update one js file and have the code be updated across all the other files that run off of it. Basically, I want to avoid telling the dependents to update explicitly or I might as well just copy and paste the new code over.

Comment: You don't have to use npm with the module systems I detailed above. For example, you can `require` a js file in `workspace/plugins/myplugin.js` from `workspace/back-end-js/index.js` by calling `var myplugin = require('../plugins/myplugin');`.